# How to pair SQL records in true/false partners

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to calculate shift times based on records imported from my time clock. I know this type of problem has been solved over and over again but my situation requires an extra subtlety that I can't figure out or find an answer online. My time clock yields records such as these:

```
Employee ID,Date,Time,Shift Start/End,Job ID <br/>
001,07/12/16,08:00:00 AM,TRUE,h010 <br/>
001,07/12/16,12:00:00 PM,FALSE,h010 <br/>
```

I want to be able to calculate the time difference between the shift start (`TRUE`) time and shift end (`FALSE`) time when the employee ID & date & job ID match. I can do that currently using my SQL code below, however my problem arises when the same employee uses the same job code on the same date (which happens quite frequently for us). For instance, my code will not suffice if I have the following records:

```
Employee ID,Date,Time,Shift Start/End,Job ID <br/>
001,07/12/16,08:00:00 AM,TRUE,h010 <br/>
001,07/12/16,12:00:00 PM,FALSE,h010 <br/>
001,07/12/16,12:30:00 PM,TRUE,h010 <br/>
001,07/12/16,05:00:00 PM,FALSE,h010 <br/>
```

My query yields 4 records:

1. end time 1 - start time 1, 4 hours
2. end time 1 - start time 2, 0.5 hours
3. end time 2 - start time 1, 9 hours
4. end time 2 - start time 2, 4.5 hours

when I only want it to return records 1 and 4. I understand why SQL returns 4 records, but how can I iterate through the data and perform the timediff calculation on only corresponding shift start and end records, so that they may be summed up over the week for payroll?

Is this possible in SQL without adding an extra field (to identify this is the second/third/fourth/etc time I've done this job today - which will undoubtedly lead to data-entry and payroll errors)?

All help is much appreciated!

(I have my time-data table, poorly named `time_testing`, called twice- `time_testing` and `time_testing_1`)

```
SELECT
  `time_testing`.`Employee ID`,
  `time_testing`.`Date`,
  `time_testing`.`In/Out`,
  `time_testing_1`.`In/Out`,
  HOUR( TIMEDIFF( `time_testing_1`.`time`,`time_testing`.`time` ) )
     + MINUTE( TIMEDIFF( `time_testing_1`.`time`, `time_testing`.`time` ) ) / 60,
  `time_testing`.`Job ID`
FROM
  `orchard_run`.`time_testing` AS `time_testing_1`,
  `orchard_run`.`time_testing` AS `time_testing`
WHERE
  `time_testing_1`.`Employee ID` = `time_testing`.`Employee ID`
  AND `time_testing_1`.`Date` = `time_testing`.`Date`
  AND `time_testing_1`.`Job ID` = `time_testing`.`Job ID`
  AND `time_testing`.`In/Out` = TRUE
  AND `time_testing_1`.`In/Out` = FALSE
```

Comment: So you don't have any third-shifters, who may clock in the evening of one day, and clock out the morning of the next?

Comment: That is correct. No shifts pass across midnight (currently anyway)